# insert into postgresql table using c#

Tags: c#, postgresql, foreign-keys

i have two postgreSQL tables linked by a foreign key.
I want to insert into the second table the data coming from the first table primary key.
I wrote that in my c# application :

```
command1.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE table1(ID CHAR(256) CONSTRAINT id PRIMARY KEY, Title CHAR)";
command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
command1.CommandText = "insert into projects (ID, Title)" + "values(@id, @title);";
command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ID);
command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title",Title);
command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

For the second table:

```
command2.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE table2(table1id CHAR(256), champs1 CHAR(256), foreign key (table1id) references table1(ID))";
command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The problem is that i dont know how to insert in table 2 the first column which is the primary key of the first table.

Any thoughts about that ?
Thank you for your help :)

Comment: when you wanna insert the value in second table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add following code.

```
cmd3=new SqlCommand("insert into table2 values(@table1id,@champs1,@table1id2)",conn);
cmd3.parameter.AddWithValue("@table1id",ID);//ID=ID of first table
cmd3.parameter.AddWithValue("@champs1",chaps);
cmd3.parameter.AddWithValue("@table1id2",ID);//ID=ID of first table
cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Hope its helpful.